# mysql query that has IF condition to replace values

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible using MySQL to have a mysql condition that queries data and if the value is NULL it replaces that value with nothing.  The query below will display data like the example below:

Broncos | 49 | Ravens 27
Colts | NULL | Chargers | NULL

Is there a way I can build the query so that it will change the results above to the ones below where it just replaces NULL with nothing?

Broncos | 49 | Ravens 27
Colts | | Chargers |

```
SELECT Home, Home_Score, Away, Away_Score FROM `NFL_Games` WHERE Week=6 order by
(case Day
 when 'Thu' then 1
 when 'Sat' then 2
 when 'Sun' then 3
 when 'Mon' then 4
 else 5 end), 
 Day, Time ASC
```

Comment: where would I put that in the query?

Comment: `select ifnull(Away, '') as away, ifull(Away_Score,0) as Away_Score from NFL_Games`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `coalesce()` or `ifnull()`

```
SELECT Home, 
       Home_Score, 
       Away, 
       coalesce(Away_Score, '') as Away_Score 
FROM `NFL_Games`
```

Comment: where would I put that in my query?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use the isnull () function. Isnull takes two parameters, the first one is the expression you want to evaluate as null and the second one is the value you want as output if the expression is null. Something like select isnull (column, 0) will return 0 if column is null. Maybe doesnt work in mysql.

Comment: the [mysql isnull](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) function doesn't behave like you think it does...

Comment: Maybe my explanation isnt correct but isnull behaviour with sql server is like i said

Comment: Sorry im spanish and i may misuse some words.